# Getting images from a particular folder

Tags: android, camera, android-cursor, save-image

I am trying to save the image in the folder which is captured using camera.
The image does get saved in the particular folder but there is another copy of the same image in the "Camera" folder.
This happens only in Android Version 2.2.1.

When I tried the same case in android version 4.1.2, there is only one copy saved in the particular folder and not in "Camera" folder.

This is the code I am using to start the camera and save the image in "MyFolder".

```
Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
 File storagePath = new 
 File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
 + "/MyFolder/");   
 if(!storagePath.isDirectory()){  
     storagePath.mkdirs();  
 }   
 File myImage = new File(storagePath,Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");  
 Uri fromURI=Uri.fromFile(myImage);   
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fromURI);  
 startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After saving the image, I will create a custom Gallery view where I will try to get all the images so that the user can select any one of the image.when I try getting images, the new image which is taken from the camera is not retrieved in the cursor.

This is the code I am using to get all the images...

```
 final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
 final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";  
 Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,null,null, orderBy);
```

In Android V 2.2.1, since the copy of the image is saved in "Camera" folder, I get the new image, but in Android V 4.1.2, I don't get the image in the cursor.

Does anyone know how to get the image from a particular folder??

TIA,
VijayRaj